# How do I show the function parameter names in function calls (not as tooltips but actually written) or declarations

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In the Image a good example is the InitAbilityActor info function call or the Binds declaration. For the info you'll see "InOwnerActor: this", so the "InOwnerActor" label placed there is what I'm asking about.
I was watching an Unreal Engine tutorial and saw the author casually doing this, and I didn't know that it existed. I'm including a screenshot of what I mean. As you can see, it's not a tooltip or intellisense related (I don't think).  Is it a Visual Studio feature (I have VS2019), a new option in the language, or some VS add-on that lets you do that? I do like that feature in Python, so if it's possible in C++, that would be great.
[image]

Comment: It wasn't clear what I'm supposed to be seeing. Is it the light bulb icon on line 107? The funny circle on line 92? Eventually, I think you're referring to the parameter hints in the function calls. [Showing inline parameter hints on Visual Studio 2019](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/showing-inline-parameter-hints-visual-studio-2019-renan-costa-alencar).

Comment: Unfortunately, you did not highlight or mark or circle whatever it is that you want us to see in that image, making your question totally unclear.

Comment: @RaymondChen yes, inline parameters it is!  For 2019 it only works for Visual Basic and C#. I need 2022 17.2 to use it on C++.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot is most likely showing the [inlay hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Inlay_hints_in_CPP.html) feature of the Resharper C++ addin.

I am not aware of any other readily available addin or built-in option that allows this for C++. Note that Visual Studio supports it out-of-the-box for [C# and Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-advanced?view=vs-2019#inline-hints) since [VS 2019 v16.8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-v16-8-preview-2/), but not for C++.

EDIT: As noted in the comments, the [2nd preview of Visual Studio 2022 17.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview#17.2.0-pre.2.0) contains this as an experimental feature, too.

Comment: I haven't personally verified but supposedly VS 2022 17.2 has it on C++

Comment: Huh, indeed, the preview is supposed to have it. That's neat. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022 you can enable this by

1. going to tools in the dropdown
2. selecting options from the menu
3. in options modal, expand Text Editor, on the left hand side.
4. drill down into C/C++, expand the carrot
5. click IntelliSense
6. there should be a "Inline Hints" section on the right hand side, you want to "Enable inline hints".

Gl!